# eigenvalue column sum equals one linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

What does the following imply about the eigenvalues of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$:

The sum of the entries in each column equals $1$.

Thank you!

Comment: Why did you tag this with numerical-linear algebra tag ?

Comment: because of the warning of "quality standards" sorry about that..

Comment: If that was the reason then I removed the tag for you

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Prove that if the sum of every row is a constant $k$ then $k$
is an eigenvalue of $A$ with a corresponding eigenvector $(1,...,1)^{T}$.

Recall that $k$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $k$ is an
eigenvalue of $A^{T}$